# How to properly add color from config

Tags: java, yaml, config, bukkit

Upon **plenty** research i have found dozens of methods doing basically the same thing; which is to get in the chat.

But ..

```js
public static void sendPlayer(Player p, String s){
    if (sm.getPrefixUse()) {

        // - Method 1 
        String string = s.replaceAll("(&([a-f0-9]))", "\u00A7$2"); 
        p.sendMessage("[" + sm.getPrefixName().replaceAll("(&([a-f0-9]))", "\u00A7$2") + "]" + string);
        // This is one method but does not work - no colour in chat

        // - Method 2 
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', sm.getPrefixName()) + ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', s));
        // Heres another- no colour in chat

        // - Method 3
        String working = "&4This works ".replaceAll("(&([a-f0-9]))", "\u00A7$2");
        p.sendMessage(working);

        // - Method 4
        String thistoo = "&4This too works";
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', thistoo));
    } else{
        p.sendMessage(s);
    }
}
```

Method 1 and 2 doesnt show color in chat - when i get a string from the config

Method 3 and 4 works, basically same as above but the string is defined here

How do i get a string from the config and send it to the player with the correct color

EDIT :
Lets say this was my config

```html
 prefix:

    use: true # By default it is true [true/false]
    # true = Adds a prefix to the messages
    # false = Doesnt add a prefix to the messages

    name: &4Hub
    # Plugin prefix - prefix to appear before messages
```

on the message it would return null if i add the color code to it

```html
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
        if(sm.getMotdUse()){
            ChatManager.sendPlayer(p, sm.getMotdMessage());
            return;
        }
```

..... something ...

then

```html
public static void sendPlayer(Player p, String s){
        if (sm.getPrefixUse()) {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', s));
            p.sendMessage(s.replaceAll("&", "§"));
        } else{
            p.sendMessage(s);
        }
    }
```

basic summary if motd true then send motd colored message + prefix
but prefix returns null
message returns with one less word

So lets say if motd message was '&4Welcome to server'
it sends 'to server' without color

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)!

Replace `&(?=[0-9a-fA-F])` into `ChatColor.COLOR_CHAR`:

```
public static void replaceVirtualColorCodes(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("&(?=[0-9a-fA-F])", Character.toString(ChatColor.COLOR_CHAR));
}
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/rR0jO0/1) is a regex demo.

Comment: The method replaceAll(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, char)

Comment: @Raizer Eh, my bad. I added a conversion to String.

Comment: Ok i think i'm doing something wrong. Been trying to fix this same bug for 3 days now but now i just stuck ! - This method works perfectly BUT when i get a string from a config file. It either returns null or removes the first word

Comment: @Raizer I suppose you may be doing it wrong somewhere else, effectively voiding all the effort building this particular method. Would you like to post the entire code of the test plugin (as well as test files) in a text hosting software of some description and then leave it here in the comments? I may be busy at times though, but the method mentioned in my answer certainly works.

Comment: Solved - in the config file the string needs to be surrounded by quotes